# Showing progress message during file upload in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I created a web page in C# webform.  It uses the UpdateProgress control to show an "Uploading file..." message while the server is processing. In order for the fileupload control to work, I need to put the button control in PostBackTrigger.  However, in doing so, the UpdateProgress no longer works. If I take the button control out of the PostBackTrigger, the UpdateProgress works, but the fileupload control doesn't.  Is there a solution?

```
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm1"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="PageUpdateProgress">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Uploading file...
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Panel">
            <!-- Remove the trigger to make the update panel work, but file upload won't work -->
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFileUpload" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1" /><br /><br />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFileUpload" Text="Upload File" OnClick="x_Click" /><br /><br />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
        protected void x_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                label1.Text = "HasFile is true";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "HasFile is false";
            }
        }
```